# Has anyone had any issues with MySQL 5.1 and ExpressionEngine?

Tags: expressionengine

Our main client server is running MySQL 5.0.96, but we'd like to upgrade to 5.1. We're running a couple of older EE1.6 sites (non older than 1.6.7 iirc), and the rest are EE2.2+

Are there any gotchas/problems we might encounter (maybe in our custom self-wrriten add-ons) when we upgrade?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run many EE installs with MySQL 5.1+ clients with no issues. Unless your SQL in custom add-on is really sloppy and you're running MySQL in STRICT mode, I can't see any issues.

Answer (score 1):

My production server runs 5.1 and both my local and dev servers run 5.5 without issue, so I doubt you'll run into any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Currently running 5.5.28 without any problem.